# Javafx listview with CheckBoxListCell doesn't work with Drag and Drop

Tags: java, listview, javafx, checkbox, drag-and-drop

I have a `ListView` with with a custom CheckBox Item called `CheckBoxListItem`. Everthing looks good but now I need to implement Drag and Drop for easier sorting.

I know that I have to use a custom `CellFactory` and set the Drag and Drop Events to the cell itself. My Problem is that I already have a `CellFactory` and dont know how to add the Events.

The commented code is what I think could be the way to do it but the `updateItem` method doesn't worked.

---

**My main class:**

```
public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        ListView<CheckBoxListItem> listView = new ListView<>();
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(listView);
        scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

        for(int i=1; i<15; i++) {
            listView.getItems().add(new CheckBoxListItem("Value"+i));
        }

        listView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(CheckBoxListItem::selectedProperty, new StringConverter<    CheckBoxListItem>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(CheckBoxListItem object) {
                return object.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public CheckBoxListItem fromString(String string) {
                return null;
            }
        }));

        /*
        ObjectProperty<CheckBoxListCell<CheckBoxListItem>> dragSource = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> {
            CheckBoxListCell<CheckBoxListItem> cell = new CheckBoxListCell<CheckBoxListItem>(){
                @Override
                public void updateItem(CheckBoxListItem item , boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item == null) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }else {
                        setGraphic(?????);
                    }
                }
            };

            cell.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
                //TODO
            });
            cell.setOnDragOver(event -> {
                //TODO
            });
            cell.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
                //TODO
            });
            return cell ;
        });
        */

        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane, 350, 450);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

**and CheckBoxListItem.java:**

```
public class CheckBoxListItem {
    private ReadOnlyStringWrapper name = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper();
    private BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    public CheckBoxListItem(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public CheckBoxListItem(String name, boolean selected) {
        this.name.set(name);
        this.selected.set(selected);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        return selected;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected.get();
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected.set(selected);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390888/dragging-and-dropping-list-view-items-between-different-javafx-windows

Comment: I know but is was without Checkboxes @Sedrick

Comment: extend CheckBoxListCell and add your handlers there

Comment: @kleopatra I tried it but doesn't worked. Could you share a working example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is something you have to combine both your approaches. You can merely mimic what CheckBoxListCell.forListView() internally does. i.e, creating a new CheckBoxListCell with the observableProperty and converter. I just remodified your demo to below and it works as expected.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxListCell;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        ListView<CheckBoxListItem> listView = new ListView<>();
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(listView);
        scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

        for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
            listView.getItems().add(new CheckBoxListItem("Value" + i));
        }

//        listView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(CheckBoxListItem::selectedProperty, new StringConverter<    CheckBoxListItem>() {
//            @Override
//            public String toString(CheckBoxListItem object) {
//                return object.getName();
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public CheckBoxListItem fromString(String string) {
//                return null;
//            }
//        }));


        ObjectProperty<CheckBoxListCell<CheckBoxListItem>> dragSource = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> {
            CheckBoxListCell<CheckBoxListItem> cell = new CheckBoxListCell<>(CheckBoxListItem::selectedProperty, new StringConverter<CheckBoxListItem>() {
                @Override
                public String toString(CheckBoxListItem object) {
                    return object.getName();
                }

                @Override
                public CheckBoxListItem fromString(String string) {
                    return null;
                }
            });

            cell.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
                System.out.println("Detected fired...");
            });
            cell.setOnDragOver(event -> {
                System.out.println("DragOver fired...");
            });
            cell.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
                System.out.println("DragDropped fired...");
            });
            return cell;
        });


        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane, 350, 450);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```